# Solve this double integration

Tags: integration, complex-integration

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_x^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos y}{y} \, dy \,  dx=\text{ ?}$$ 
I have tried this question but don't have any idea how to integrate $\dfrac{\cos y}{y}$. I have studied math up to 12th. Many many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the order of integration, you will get an integral

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^y \cdots $$ (why?? Make a drawing of the integration region)

The final value of yout integral is 1.